# Prolog - Calculate fastest travel between 2 locations given different travel modes

Tags: search, prolog, shortest-path

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the fastest journey between two places, given different travel modes. My factbase starts with a predicate `route(Src, Dest, Distance, TravelMode)` and input is via the predicate `journey(Src, Dest, TravelMode)` which should output the fastest travel mode to use. (Basically whichever has the shortest time.)

However, it says that `TravelMode` is a string and if it contains `f`, it means the path can be traveled on foot, `c` for car, `t` for train and `p` for plane. This has me confused since I don't really understand how to search the String `TravelMode` and only run the corresponding time functions for the travel modes included.

Below is my code and right now, it's only able to calculate the time between places (`time_f`, etc), although I believe my time predicate is wrong since I think it's supposed to be just one general function.

I also did try coding the `journey` predicate however, it only seems to output `true` / `false` and no values which probably means my `route` / `speed` predicate is wrong.

Am I on the right path? I've been stuck on this and I'd really appreciate any help to steer me in the correct direction / help explain what I have gotten wrong in here.

Not sure if everyone understands but I added the program specs just so that it could be clearer to understand

[image: Problem Statement]

```
/* Sample set of facts */
route(dublin, cork, 200, 'fct').
route(cork, dublin, 200, 'fct').
route(cork, corkAirport, 20, 'fc').
route(corkAirport, cork, 25, 'fc').
route(dublin, dublinAirport, 10, 'fc').
route(dublinAirport, dublin, 20, 'fc').
route(dublinAirport, corkAirport, 225, 'p').
route(corkAirport, dublinAirport, 225, 'p').

/* Speed of mode of transport used */
speed(foot, 5).
speed(car, 80).
speed(train, 100).
speed(plane, 500).

/* Time between 2 cities, given specified transportation mode */
time_f(City1, City2, Time) :-
    route(City1, City2, Distance, _),
    speed(foot, Speed),
    Time is (Distance / Speed), 
    write('Time travelling between '), write(City1), write(' and '), write(City2), write(' via foot is: '), write(Time), nl.

time_c(City1, City2, Time) :-
    route(City1, City2, Distance, _),
    speed(car, Speed),
    Time is (Distance / Speed), 
    write('Time travelling between '), write(City1), write(' and '), write(City2), write(' via car is: '), write(Time), nl.

time_t(City1, City2, Time) :-
    route(City1, City2, Distance, _),
    speed(train, Speed),
    Time is (Distance / Speed), 
    write('Time travelling between '), write(City1), write(' and '), write(City2), write(' via train is: '), write(Time), nl.

time_p(City1, City2, Time) :-
    route(City1, City2, Distance, _),
    speed(plane, Speed),
    Time is (Distance / Speed), 
    write('Time travelling between '), write(City1), write(' and '), write(City2), write(' via plane is: '), write(Time), nl.


/* Solve for fastest journey */
journey(City1, City2, TravelModes) :-
    route(City1, City2, Distance, TravelModes),
    speed('TravelModes', Speed),
    Time is (Distance / Speed), 
    write('Time travelling between '), write(City1), write(' and '), write(City2), write(' via '), write(TravelModes), 
    write(' is: '), write(Time), nl.
```

**EDIT:**

I tried to implement some changes. Especially that of detecting if mode is part of the string.

```
/* Sample set of facts */
route(dublin, cork, 200, fct).
route(dublin, dublinAirport, 10, fc).
route(dublinAirport, corkAirport, 225, p).

/* Speed of mode of transport used */
speed(f, 5).
speed(c, 80).
speed(t, 100).
speed(p, 500). 

/* Program Flow 
1. Input journey(City1, City2, TravelModes).
2. Check if City1 and City2 can be traveled (or path exists between them)
3. Access time function
4. Get travel time between City1 and City2 for TravelModes used
5. Select lowest travel time and output it.
*/

/* Checks if mode is in string */
availableMode(Mode, TravelModes) :- forall(sub_atom(Mode,_,1,_,C), sub_atom(TravelModes,_,1,_,C)).

/* Check mode of transport */

journey(City1, City2, TravelModes) :-
    route(City1, City2, Distance, TravelModes),
    availableMode(Mode, TravelModes),
    speed(Mode, Speed),
    Time is (Distance / Speed),
    write('Time between '), write(City1), write(' and '), write(City2), write(' via '), write(Mode), write(' is: '),
    write(Time), n1.
```

**EDIT 2:**

Currently, this is able to check the `TravelMode` input and calculate the necessary time. However, it doesn't store the output in a list of which the goal is to select the lowest time between routes and output that time.

```
/* Sample set of facts */
route(dublin, cork, 200, fct).
route(dublin, dublinAirport, 10, fc).
route(dublinAirport, corkAirport, 225, p).

/* Speed of mode of transport used */
speed(f, 5).
speed(c, 80).
speed(t, 100).
speed(p, 500). 

/* Checks if mode is in string */
availableMode(Mode, TravelModes) :- sub_atom(TravelModes,_,1,_,Mode).

/* Read journey user input */
journey(City1, City2, TravelModes) :-
    route(City1, City2, Distance, TravelModes),
    availableMode(Mode, TravelModes),
    speed(Mode, Speed),
    Time is (Distance / Speed),
    write('Time between '), write(City1), write(' and '), write(City2), write(' via '), write(Mode), write(' is: '),
    write(Time), nl.
```

**EDIT 3:**

Implemented time variable to secondary `journey predicate`. Tried to implement `all(Solutions)` and finding the minimum variable, though I believe I am still missing out something since it only outputs `true` / `false`.

```
/* Sample set of facts */
route(dublin, cork, 200, fct).
route(dublinAirport, dublin, 20, fc).
route(dublinAirport, corkAirport, 225, p).

/* Speed of mode of transport used */
speed(f, 5).
speed(c, 80).
speed(t, 100).
speed(p, 500). 

/* Checks if mode is in string */
availableMode(Mode, TravelModes) :- sub_atom(TravelModes,_,1,_,Mode).

journey(City1, City2, TravelModes) :-
    route(City1, City2, Distance, TravelModes),
    availableMode(Mode, TravelModes),
    speed(Mode, Speed),
    Time is (Distance / Speed),
    write('Time between '), write(City1), write(' and '), write(City2), write(' via '), write(Mode), write(' is: '),
    write(Time), nl.

/* Keep definition of journey but include a time variable that can be utilized */
journey(City1, City2, TravelModes) :- journey(City1, City2, TravelModes, _Time).

/* journey using time variable */
journey(City1, City2, TravelModes, Time) :- 
    route(City1, City2, Distance, TravelModes),
    availableMode(Mode, TravelModes),
    speed(Mode, Speed),
    Time is (Distance / Speed).

/* Collecting all solutions */
all(Solutions) :- findall([City1, City2, TravelModes, Time], journey(City1, City2, TravelModes, Time), Solutions).

/* Finding minimum solution */
find_min(S, Solutions) :- all(Solutions).
```

**EDIT 4:**

Implemented (solving for the solutions recursively and storing them in a list). Also removed the redundant `journey/3`. Currently in the process of fixing the code to show just one solution set (aka the final solution with the lowest time).

```
/* Sample set of facts */
route(dublin, cork, 200, fct).
route(cork, dublin, 200, fct).
route(cork, corkAirport, 20, fc).
route(corkAirport, cork, 25, fc).
route(dublin, dublinAirport, 10, fc).
route(dublinAirport, dublin, 20, fc).
route(dublinAirport, corkAirport, 225, p).
route(corkAirport, dublinAirport, 225, p).

/* Speed of mode of transport used */
speed(f, 5).
speed(c, 80).
speed(t, 100).
speed(p, 500). 

/* Checks if mode is in string */
availableMode(Mode, TravelModes) :- sub_atom(TravelModes,_,1,_,Mode).

/* Keep definition of journey but include a time variable that can be utilized */
journey(City1, City2, TravelModes) :- journey(City1, City2, TravelModes, _Time).

/* journey using time variable */
journey(City1, City2, TravelModes, Time) :- 
    route(City1, City2, Distance, TravelModes),
    availableMode(Mode, TravelModes),
    speed(Mode, Speed),
    Time is (Distance / Speed),
    write('Time between '), write(City1), write(' and '), write(City2), write(' via '), write(Mode), write(' is: '),
    write(Time), nl.

/* Collecting all solutions */
all(Solutions) :- findall([City1, City2, TravelModes, Time], journey(City1, City2, TravelModes, Time), Solutions).

/* Recursion to find minimum travel time */
% Using the \+ (not provable operator) which discards the unnecessary solution
% Allowing us to retain the solutions with lowest time
% After recursively going thru the list, the accumulator list is set to the final solution list (aka the lowest time)
minimize([],Sol,Sol).
minimize([S|Ss],SolAcc,FinSol) :- S = [Cy1, Cy2, _, _],
                                  \+ member([Cy1, Cy2, _, _], SolAcc),
                                  minimize(Ss,[S|SolAcc],FinSol).
minimize([S|Ss],SolAcc,FinSol) :- S = [Cy1, Cy2, _MyMd, MyTi],
                                  member([Cy1, Cy2, _OtherMd, OtherTi], SolAcc),
                                  OtherTi < MyTi,
                                  minimize(Ss,SolAcc,FinSol).
minimize([S|Ss],SolAcc,FinSol) :- S = [Cy1, Cy2, _MyMd, MyTi],
                                  member([Cy1, Cy2, _OtherMd, OtherTi], SolAcc),
                                  OtherTi >= MyTi,
                                  delete(SolAcc, [Cy1, Cy2,_,_], SolAcc2),
                                  minimize(Ss,[S|SolAcc2],FinSol).

/* Finding minimum solution */
find_min(MinimizedSolutions) :- all(Solutions),minimize(Solutions,[],MinimizedSolutions).
```

Comment: `'fct'` means the same thing without quotes: it is an atom either way. So the predicate you want is probably something like `sub_atom(fct, _, 1, _, t)`, to determine if your mode-of-transport contains a `t`.

Comment: Ah I see, though how do you make it calculate differently if it contains both f and c, or contains f only or f, c, t and p?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer hi sir! Is the way that I have outlined my program flow alright?

1. Input journey(City1, City2, TravelModes)
2. Check if City1 and City2 can be traveled (or path exists between them)
3. Access time function
4. Get travel time between City1 and City2 for TravelModes used
5. Select lowest travel time and output it.

Comment: @30pewpew Yes this looks good, although it is better to not think in terms of "program flow" but in terms of a "database" (extensional or explicitly specified part: `route/3` and `speed/2` predicates; intensional or computed part:  `availableMode/2` and `journey/3`) and then launching a query against it: `journey(C1,C2,TM)`. The `availableMode/2` predicate should just be `availableMode(Mode, TravelModes) :- sub_atom(TravelModes,_,1,_,Mode).`, no?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Ah I see, and yes! You are right, when I inputted journey(dublin, cork, fct). It was able to output the 3 desired values: (f: 40, c: 2.5, and t: 2)! Really exciting to see that the program is going somewhere now hehe. 

However, how would I then go about selecting the lowest value among the 3? Should it be in storing it via a list or should I store it in a variable and just rewrite it? (My apologies, that I still suck and feel stuck in the sense that I still envision programming it as if I was on C, C++, Java, etc)

Comment: @30pewpew To get out the minimum time, you want to have the variable for Time visible "on the left of :- " for `journey`: `journey(C1,C2,TM,Time) :- ...`. Then collect all solutions that can be generated by Prolog through its backtracking in another variable using `bagof/3` via a new predicate: `all(Solutions) :- bagof([C1,C2,TM,Time],journey(C1,C2,TM,Time),Solutions)`, then add yet another predicate `find_min(S,Solutions) :- ...` to find the minimum in `Solutions`.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer thank you for this sir! Though I'm quite confused as to the first part that you said, so does that mean that I would have to edit the journey predicate and include another additional variable (which is Time). 

Also would using findall, be perfectly fine as well?

Comment: I got lost so I made it in a list view:  
1. Variable for time on left of journey - something like<br/>
    findall(Time, journey(City1, City2, TravelModes, Time)
**However

Comment: @30pewpew Yes, you want to "return" the value for Time through the modified `journey` predicate. The variable `Time` is bound with a value in the body, and the caller (in this case, `bagof`) can collect it via the head. You can certainly use `findall` too. See [Finding all Solutions to a Goal](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer ahh I see, though I just wanted to ask, does that mean that I'd still be able to input journey(City1, City2, TravelModes) and the output will still remain the same (though just a single output instead of the many outputs awhile ago)? Is that correct?

Comment: @30pewpew No, you will have to keep a definition for `journey/3` in addition to the new `journey/4`. Like so: `journey(City1, City2, TravelModes) :- journey(City1, City2, TravelModes, _Time)`. In that way, "calling" `journey/3` will "call" `journey/4`, which binds a value to `_Time`. That variable is then disregarded (to indicate that to the human reader, the variable starts with an `_`)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Oh I see, thank you for this sir! I'll code it as you have specified!

Comment: @DavidTonhofer hi sir! I tried to implement what you said in the comments above. I think it's close since there's no errors but I do believe that I'm lacking something since in my find_min(S, Solutions) :- all(Solutions). The S is just a singleton variable and its not linked to anything.

Comment: You also should get rid of one of the two journey/3. One is redundant. Move the writes to the journey/3 which calls journey/4, then delete the original journey/3.

Comment: @David Tonhofer I apologize for this sir, will make sure to do so! Ah I see, the al

Comment: @David Tonhofer so this was what you were talking about (collecting all solutions and minimizing). However, it still doesnt output a single time variable (even if I just run the find_min function only.) Is that because I have yet to select a minimum?

Comment: @DanielLyons Many thanks as well for your help on this! :D

Answer (score 0):

Answer to adding "minimization" predicate which selects those City-City paths that have lowest time. *(This predicate is now in "Edit 4" of the question)*

The SWI Prolog documentation for `findall` or `bagof` is [here](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions).

Note that `findall` belows is given the expression `journey(City1, City2, TravelModes, Time)` as a **term** but "elevates" it to a **goal** (i.e. a callable predicate). This is [meta-call](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=metacall) functionality and very much beyond first-order logic, similar to building Java code through string appends, compiling it, then running it. Editors should highlight that part in inverse...

```
/* Collecting all solutions */
all(Solutions) :- findall([City1, City2, TravelModes, Time], journey(City1, City2, TravelModes, Time), Solutions).

minimize([],Sol,Sol).
minimize([S|Ss],SolAcc,FinSol) :- S = [Cy1, Cy2, _, _],
                                  \+ member([Cy1, Cy2, _, _], SolAcc),
                                  minimize(Ss,[S|SolAcc],FinSol).
minimize([S|Ss],SolAcc,FinSol) :- S = [Cy1, Cy2, _MyMd, MyTi],
                                  member([Cy1, Cy2, _OtherMd, OtherTi], SolAcc),
                                  OtherTi < MyTi,
                                  minimize(Ss,SolAcc,FinSol).
minimize([S|Ss],SolAcc,FinSol) :- S = [Cy1, Cy2, _MyMd, MyTi],
                                  member([Cy1, Cy2, _OtherMd, OtherTi], SolAcc),
                                  OtherTi >= MyTi,
                                  delete(SolAcc, [Cy1, Cy2,_,_], SolAcc2),
                                  minimize(Ss,[S|SolAcc2],FinSol).


/* Finding minimum solution */
find_min(MinimizedSolutions) :- all(Solutions),minimize(Solutions,[],MinimizedSolutions).
```

**Clarification to answer question in comments**

If you think of the program as defining a flow of data (see lovingly hand-drawn diagram below), then first `Solutions` is set-to (or "unified-with") a list of all possible solutions for `journey(C1,C2,Tm,Ti)`, each formatted itself as list `[C1,C2,Tm,Ti]`.

The list `Solutions` flows into a box representing `minimize`. That box  also takes an empty list `[]` and is meant to unify its third argument with-the-eventual solution `MinimizedSolutions`. `minimize` calls itself (creating a new `minimize` box within itself) and behaves differently in each of the 4 cases of input it can receive as values of `Solutions` and `SolAcc`.

The idea is that `minimize` removes an element from its first input value, (a list) and adds 1 or 0 elements to its second input value, the accumulator (also a list), before calling itself. In that way when the first input value finally turns out to be `[]`, `minimize` just needs to short-circuit the second value (input) to the third value (output), which then flows outwards through the recursively imbricated boxes towards the top goal.

[image: prolog data flow]

In fact Prolog allows nasty (but compact) code to be written because it allows the expressions for case distinctions in `minimze/3` to be carcrashed into the rule head. To make `minimize` clearer and show intention, in an imaginary Prolog which only allows variables as predicate arguments in the rule head and has "guard expressions" to perform case testing to the left of an `|` in the rule body, we would have the following code:

```
% Hide the fact that we need an accumulator value by
% defining minimize/2 which calls minimize/3
% This is the "public" part of minimize and can also be done in Prolog. 

minimize(SolIn,SolOut) :- minimize(SolIn,[],SolOut).  

% This is the "private" part of minimize and uses non-Prolog "guard" syntax

minimize(SolIn,SolAcc,SolOut) :- SolIn = [] | 
                                 SolOut = SolAcc.
minimize(SolIn,SolAcc,SolOut) :- SolIn = [S|Ss],
                                 S = [Cy1, Cy2, _, _],
                                 \+ member([Cy1, Cy2, _, _], SolAcc) |
                                 minimize(Ss,[S|SolAcc],SolOut).
minimize(SolIn,SolAcc,SolOut) :- SolIn = [S|Ss],
                                 S = [Cy1, Cy2, _MyMd, MyTi],
                                 member([Cy1, Cy2, _OtherMd, OtherTi], SolAcc),
                                 OtherTi < MyTi |
                                 minimize(Ss,SolAcc,FinSol).

% etc. for the other two cases
```

The `minimize(SolIn,SolOut)` rule is just there to show to the next guy who has to maintain this that the arity-2 predicate `minimize/2` is what "client code" would use. `minimize/2`  passes the work directly to  the actual "implementation" which is an arity-3 predicate `minimize/3`:  `minimize(SolIn,SolAcc,SolOut)`.

For the latter, the recursive traversal through the `SolIn` list is kicked off by the body `minimize(SolIn,[],SolOut)`.

If the program were [modularized](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=defmodule), `minimize(SolIn,SolOut)` would be what's being exported by the module. One would also mark what the implementation regards has "in" and "out" variables (sadly only in the comment, the compiler doesn't handle those) according to [mode flags](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=preddesc): `minimize(+SolIn,-SolOut)`

Again, this has aspects of imperative programming style "procedure calls" but I always visualize the thread or flow of information going into the "predicate box" at certain argument position and coming back out at another position, much like stitching. (Add things like [freeze/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=freeze/2) and the thread needs to have tokens moving along it too, but that's for another time)

Comment: I'd just like to ask if my understanding of how this minimization predicate works. So it collects all the solutions (basically the findall that you were talking about yesterday). Then you store it in the predicate all(Solutions). Now this contains all the solutions (can be checked when you run all(Solutions)) Now goal is to eventually get just the solution with the lowest value. So that's the minimize and it's a list. Then checks if solution is a member of the all(Solutions), if not then its discarded. Then compares time values, if its smaller, its stored, higher, discarded.

Comment: @30pewpew I think you are close. Added some text to explain this.

Comment: thank you for this, the diagram definitely makes things a ton clearer! I'd just like to ask if the the second code minimize(SolIn, SolOut) etc more like a pseudocode (though it doesn't seem like it) or actual revisions to the minimization predicate?